# Centered html button link

Tags: html

I know very little about HTML. I have been searching for and playing with an answer to this problem for several hours. I am trying to make an HTML button that is centered and links to a website. Can someone please give me the code for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the button code between `<div align='center'>buttoncode</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make an HTML button that is centered and links to a website.

```
<center>
      <input type="button" value="Put Your Text Here" onClick="parent.location='http://www.google.com/'">
</center>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function DoIt(){
      window.open ('http:somewhere.net','_self',false);
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <button onclick="DoIt ()">Put Some Text Here</button>
  </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Putting the code in between

```
<center>

</center>
```

worked for me!